# p-value, hypotheses testing, type II error

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

In hypotheses testing, the $p$-value is the smallest significance level $\alpha$ at which the test rejects $H_0$ if $H_0$ is in fact true.

Is there a similar concept as is $p$-value also for the type-II error $\beta$?

Comment: For the reference of my first sentence see 5.3.11 [here](http://leteckaposta.cz/362022227).

Comment: Could you please reword yopur last sentence "Rejection region is required to find $β$" ?I didn't catch the meaning of it.

Comment: Erasing previous comment, which does not seem to have been helpful. Suggest you review definitions of significance level, p-value, Type I and II errors, & rejection region.